# $\int\sqrt{1-a\cos x}\ dx$

Tags: calculus

How to evaluate, for constant $a$,
$$\int\sqrt{1-a\cos x}\ dx?$$

Comment: this integral leads to an elliptic one

Comment: I can see in Mathematica the answer. I just wanted to know a few steps where it leads me to an integral that can not be solved analytically with traditional calculus methods. How do I know that an integral can not be solved with simple calculus through some substitutions?

Answer (score 1):

$$cos^2x/2-\sin^2x/2=cosx$$
and $$sin^2x/2+cos^2x/2=1$$
$$1+acosx=(1+a)cos^2x/2+(1-a)sin^2x/2$$
and use differentiation under integral sign Leibniz theorem.